# How to pass String Arrays in an instance?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which I call from the `MainActivity` class.

Here is the fragment code where there is no error :

```
public class PersonFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String ARG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    
    ListView lst;
    
    
    String[] name = {"Dockar","Nilson"};
    
    String[] firstname = {"Jack","Michel"};
    
    
    public static PersonFragment newInstance(String[] name, String[] firstname) {
        PersonFragment fragment = new PersonFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray(ARG_NAME, name);
        args.putStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    
    }
    
    Activity mainActivity;
    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_fragment, container, false);
    
        lst = view.findViewById(R.id.listviewperson);
        CustomeListviewAdapterTest customeListview = new CustomeListviewAdapterTest(this.mainActivity,name,firtname);
        lst.setAdapter(customeListview);
    
        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Jack.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }if(position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Michel.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
            }
        });
    
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            name = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_NAME);
            firstname = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME);
    
        }
    
        return view;
    }
```

Now I want to call it from the `MainActivity`. So I put this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_person:
            PersonFragment fragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(HAVE ERROR HERE CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL NAME, CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL FIRSTNAME);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            break;
```

Can someone help how to fix please and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace. :)

Comment: `PersonFragment fragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(HAVE ERROR HERE CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL NAME, CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL FIRSTNAME);` hard to tell what the error is without seeing the *actual* code that causes the error. Please show a [example].